# Theorems of properties of rational right triangles proving Pythagorean triples

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, triangles, pythagorean-triples

Let’s say we have a triple of integers $(a,b,c)$ which is assumed to be a Pythagorean triple, so that $$a^2+b^2=c^2.\tag{$\star$}$$
Without using ($\star$) directly or indirectly — but using other properties and theorems related to rational right triangles — what are ways of proving that $(a,b,c)$ is or is not a Pythagorean triple? I’m thinking of theorems on areas, medians, incircles and outcircles, triangle points, infinite ternary tree constructions, *etc.*

As a concrete example, consider the triple $(3,4,7)$. Without using the fact that $3^2+4^2 \ne 7^2$, how would one prove that $(3,4,7)$ is not a Pythagorean triple?

More to the point, consider the *indeterminate* triple $$(14x^3,(x^3-7)y^2, x^3y^2+7y^2-14x^3),\tag{$\dagger$}$$
which is derived from the Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+7$. That equation has no integer solutions (as proved using other algebraic methods) — I'm trying to find out if triangle properties can be used to prove the same result.

Comment: $3+4=7$ so this is a line segment.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for in general...the Pythagorean Theorem is pretty powerful.  Of course, twice the area of a right triangle is the product of the two shorter sides....and you can use Heron's formula to compute the area of any triangle given its sides and compare.  Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: The way the question is phrased, it sounds vague and hardly meaningful.  What is "powerful"?

Comment: See the edited question. By "powerful", I mean elementary triangle theorems/properties that would actually be useful to show that the indeterminate triple given can never be a rational right triangle.

Comment: @lulu: The triangle inequality! An excellent example of a useful — and surprisingly powerful — property.

Comment: @lulu: The "compare area $ab/2$ to Heron's formula" sometimes works; but most often (at least as I've used/manipulated it) it leads to a trivial confirmation of the [algebraic] area of the triangle. However, in the specific indeterminate case I gave here, I think it might actually work!

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Sorry the question irked you. You are not required to answer it, or even comment on it, of course — and you can always vote to close, if you feel that's appropriate. Fortunately, lulu has offered two useful suggestions — at least one of which I'm probably going to suggest they make into an answer — and hopefully others will, too. As for "selfies": I don't even own a cellular phone.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: No, question has merit, just the way you posed it irks me. It is the mathematician's equivalent of leet-speak, and just as silly. Why not title your question "Theorems of properties of rational right triangles proving Pythagorean triplets?" That and dropping each occurrence of "powerful", you'd have an excellent question. As it is, to participate on this site, I *do* have to read the titles, and the one you set for your question is not just meaningless (wrt. the content of the question), but irksome. The actual question underneath the irksome language is good and interesting.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Edited. Thanks for the helpful feedback!

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Thank you for editing the question. Now, it is very interesting. (Many, myself included, select questions to consider based on their titles.) I am not a mathematician, but I wonder if the Pythagorean theorem is fundamentally related to how a right triangle is half a rectangle, split along the diagonal. If the sides of the rectangle are $a$ and $b$, the diagonal is $$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$based on Euclidean length in two dimensions, as $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular by definition; which obviously leads to $$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$ being valid for a rectangle diagonal.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: Can you explain how your indeterminate triple ($\dagger$) is derived from the Mordell equation $x^2=y^3+7$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: It's derived from $y^2=x^3+7$ (you switched the variables). Evidently $xy \ne 0$, and so
\begin{align}
0 &= x^3+7-y^2  \\
&= 28x^3y^2(x^3+7-y^2)  \\
&= (14x^3)^2 + ((x^3-7)y^2)^2 - (x^3y^2+7y^2-14x^3)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Every [Diophantine] equation can be manipulated into a Pythagorean triple — in fact, many (possibly infinite?) different triples!

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Thank you! You just inspired a great idea in this direction.